# import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions not found

Tags: android, google-api-client

Why "***import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions not found***" is my case? I'm using android studio, android sdk 1.7.
I'm also add dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: how do you think some one can help you??? only if you let them know everything about the issue.. do you think you have made it??

Answer (score 5):

You need add "-android", eg:
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'

(eg: the -android flavor)

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/build.gradle has an example.